# How to make aspx pages Read Only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a condition where I need to check that if any property is **`migrated`** then set the related `aspx` pages as **`read-only`**.

**Something like below:** But here I need to create the `EnableControls()` on all required Pages which will increase the lines of code.

`EnableControls(this.Page.Form.Controls, false); // will call this from Page_Load()`

```
public void EnableControls(ControlCollection ctrl, bool isEnable)
{
    foreach (Control item in ctrl)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(Panel) || item.GetType() == typeof(HtmlGenericControl))
            EnableControls(item.Controls, isEnable);
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
            ((DropDownList)item).Enabled = isEnable;
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            ((TextBox)item).Enabled = isEnable;
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            ((Button)item).Enabled = isEnable;
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(HtmlInputButton))
            ((HtmlInputButton)item).Disabled = !isEnable;
    }
}
```

Is there any other easiest way to achieve this like create a global function and call that from required **`read-only`** pages?

Thanks! appreciate any better Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `IHttpModule` to intercept the page, check via Reflection if it is a readonly page and disable its controls based on this.

```
 public class ReadOnlyModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += (_o, _e) =>
            {
                var handler = ((HttpApplication)_o).Context.CurrentHandler;

                var page = handler as Page;
                if (page != null)
                {
                    page.PreRender += (o, e) =>
                    {
                        var readonlyPropertyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperty("IsReadonly");
                        var shouldMakeItReadonly = readonlyPropertyInfo != null && (bool)readonlyPropertyInfo.GetValue(o) == true;
                        var isEnable = !shouldMakeItReadonly;
                        EnableControls(((Page)o).Controls, isEnable);
                    };

                }
            };
        }

        public void EnableControls(ControlCollection ctrl, bool isEnable)
        {
            foreach (Control item in ctrl)
            {
                if (item.HasControls())
                    EnableControls(item.Controls, isEnable);
                else if (item is WebControl)
                    ((WebControl)item).Enabled = isEnable;
                else if (item is HtmlControl)
                    ((HtmlControl)item).Disabled = !isEnable;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

Register this module in the `httpModules` section and then you can implement the IsReadonly property in the specific pages.

As a bonus you can also add this property in the markup (aspx) file and rely on the ASP .Net compilation as this.

***Use cases***

You can place the `IsReadonly` property in the code behind (default.aspx.cs)

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public bool IsReadonly
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Or in the .aspx file itself as long as you use it like this

```
<script runat="server">
    public bool IsReadonly { get { return true; } }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks looks like a great Idea. I didn't heard about `IHttpModule` before. can you please also share link or example which shows how to register this module in `httpModules` and its complete working?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.85).aspx Just register this module

Comment: Thanks Adrian: It works like a charm.  Can we call `IsReadonly ` this property from any class file? means what if we called it ? what we need to change in current function?

Comment: Yes, I Marked it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Extension method on Page like this.

```
public static class PageExtensions{
    public static void EnableControls(this Page page,ControlCollection ctrl, bool isEnable)
            {
                if (ctrl == null)
                    ctrl = page.Controls;
                foreach (Control item in ctrl)
                {
                    if (item.Controls.Count > 0)
                        EnableControls(page, item.Controls, isEnable);

                    if (item.GetType() == typeof (DropDownList))
                        ((DropDownList) item).Enabled = isEnable;
                    else if (item.GetType() == typeof (TextBox))
                        ((TextBox) item).Enabled = isEnable;
                    else if (item.GetType() == typeof (Button))
                        ((Button) item).Enabled = isEnable;
                    else if (item.GetType() == typeof (HtmlInputButton))
                        ((HtmlInputButton) item).Disabled = !isEnable;
                }
            }
}
```

This will allow you to just call `this.EnableControls(null,false)` to disable all controls on a page

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Jordan.!

Comment: Still like to ask that, Is there any other way to get all controls disabled rather than to check for `Button`,  `DropDownList`, etc.. instead of using if-else?

Comment: @RahulHendawe You could try just doing `item.Enabled = isEnable`. I'm not sure what will happen to the HtmlInputButton since it uses Disabled. But try and see :)